# Is it possible to extract a path as the value of an entity in Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have an intent that requires the user to give a path:

> plot the file in /home/user/path

Is there a way to extract the path with dialogflow and to get its value into an entity? I think that this case cannot be approached with synonyms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO**, as DialogFlow doesn't support Regex in entities, there is no easy way to parse path value in DialogFlow using entity.
You have two options to parse Paths into an entity.

**One:** Use `@sys.any` entity in place of the path and on fulfilment side check if the value of the entity is actually a valid path or not using Regex.

**Two:** Create your own entity for paths and use `DialogFlow Agent-API` to keep updating values in that entity whenever new file/folder is created/updated/deleted in whatever file system you are working on. (Yeah this sounds crazy but I don't think there are any other options to achieve what you want)

Comment: I see. What a shame hehe. I've found that RASA does support regex to extract entities. I guess I'll switch to that. Thank you very much for confirming this cannot be done with dialogflow!